# Ruby version - Error installing Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, web, rubygems, rvm

I'm getting the next error installing RoR
How can I set the correct Ruby Version?

```
##@##:path$ ruby -v
ruby 2.0.0p247 (2013-06-27 revision 41674) [x86_64-linux]
##@##:path$ sudo gem install rails
ERROR:  Error installing rails:
    activesupport requires Ruby version >= 1.9.3.
##@##:path$
```

Comment: It sounds like your system version of Ruby is still not >= 1.9.3.  What do you get if you do `sudo ruby -v`?

Comment: If got `ruby 1.8.7`
How can I change my system version of Ruby?

Comment: Depends on your OS... StackOverflow has answers for these questions.

Comment: However, I'd recommend checking out RVM (as @Farley stated in his answer) - this way you wouldn't need to mess with the root system's ruby.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You shouldn't have to use `sudo` with `gem install ...`. That's what's causing the mismatch between Ruby versions, since `root` is using the default installed Ruby, whereas your own account is using RVM's installed version.

Updating the system version of Ruby depends on your operating system, and usually lags behind the very latest version of Ruby. I've been using 2.0 for my latest project I launched last month. I doubt big OS vendors like Ubuntu or Apple are providing that version in their latest distribution. It's best that you manage your own Rubies whenever possible.

To install 1.9.3 you can run:

```
$ rvm install 1.9.3
```

then later

```
$ rvm use 1.9.3
```

Comment: Installing Rails for all users is a different scenario. Check this documentation for a system-wide install: https://rvm.io/rvm/install

Comment: This answer doesn't really explain why the user might be seeing this message nor how to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

You have :

> @##:path$ ruby -v
>   .....
>
> @##:path$ sudo gem install rails

...you said in your [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20251429/ruby-version-error-installing-rails#comment30205697_20251429) that :

> $ sudo ruby -v

...gives you

> ruby 1.8.7

To resolve this problem you shouldn't use `sudo`, as it tries to install using root session with 1.8.7 ruby version which is not supported.

To install rails just type the following without `sudo`:

> $ gem install rails

...it should works as you've a supported ruby version (ruby 2.0.0p247)

You can check [Install Ruby on Rails · Ubuntu Linux](http://railsapps.github.io/installrubyonrails-ubuntu.html) instructions (Which I found useful) if you've more troubles.